# Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}e^{i2t}dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove that $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}e^{i2t}dt=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{4}.$$

My work: we have that
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}e^{i2t}dt=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}}{2i}-\frac{-1}{2i}=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}-1}{2i}$$
I know that $(-1)=e^{i\pi}$ and $2i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ so
$$\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}-1}{2i}=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}e^{i\pi}}{2e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}}=\frac{1}{2}e^{i\frac{5\pi}{6}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6})+i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6})\right)=\frac{1}{4}(-\sqrt{3}+1).$$
Can anyone help me find the error?

Comment: There is an extra minus sign on the evaluation of the anti-derivative at the lower limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/6}e^{i2t}dt&=\frac{e^{i \pi /3}-1}{2i}\\
&=e^{i \pi /6}\frac{e^{i \pi /6}-e^{-i \pi /6}}{2i}\\
&=e^{i \pi /6}\sin(\pi/6)\\
&=\cos(\pi/6)\sin(\pi/6)-i\sin^2(\pi/6)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{4}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{e^{i \pi /3}-1}{2i} = -\frac{i}2(\cos \frac{\pi}3 +i \sin \frac{\pi}3-1) \\
= -\frac{i}2(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2-1) \\
= \frac{-i}2(-\frac12 +i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2) \\
=\frac{i}4 -i^2\frac{\sqrt{3}}4 \\
= \frac14(\sqrt{3}+i)
$$